# Eclipse - Java import seems to be missing?

Tags: java, eclipse, jmenubar

I'm playing around with the `JMenu` class, and something unexpected happened.

I run the code below, and the `JFrame` appears, but the `MenuBar` and contents do not.
However, when I resize the `JFrame` with the mouse, the elements pop into existence.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,300);     
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // centered on monitor   
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    menubar.setVisible(true);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);

    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menubar.add(help);

    /**
     * Label and text and button
     */
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello there");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);

    JButton button = new JButton("Submit Button");
    panel.add(button);
    button.setToolTipText("this is my tooltip text");    
  }
}
```

Can anyone see anything suspicious that I can't see?

Comment: The frame is rendering before you add all its contents?  Try moving the call to `frame.setVisible(true)` to the bottom

Comment: Wow, something so friggin easy.  thanks for pointing the obvious Sam, I needed it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was simply the frame.setVisible(true);

I needed to put it farther below.

Comment: This answer should probably be Community Wiki (seeing as you got it from Sam Dufel)